# android listview fit the screen

Tags: android

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:ignore="InconsistentLayout">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contacts_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Above code list view is having some space around the corners. i need to set my list view to fit the screen.could any one give solution

Comment: Try removing the paddings from your `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

Comment: But i need swipeRefreshLayout

Comment: Dont remove the swiperefresh layout..instead remove the paddings from that.

Comment: You you have the height zero ? as I see
android:layout_height="0dp"

Answer (score 0):

you are using

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

that makes your layour wrapping listview will have margin,so to fix it,you just need to set these to 0:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:ignore="InconsistentLayout">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/contacts_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove the padding

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    tools:ignore="InconsistentLayout">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/contacts_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: hi; does removing padding worked for you, if not try to see if parent of SwipeRefreshLayout are not having padding or margin, good luck